# I cannot map on the data fetched from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga, use-effect

I fetch data from an API with Redux-Saga but I cannot use it when it updates state. It is probably because I am trying to access the data before it is loaded to the redux state.

```
//saga.js

import axios from 'axios';
import { put, takeLatest, all } from 'redux-saga/effects'
const URL = "https://api.staging.gamerarena.com/disputes/";

function* fetchInfo() {
  const res = yield axios.get(URL).then((response) => response);
  yield put({
    type: 'FETCH_INFO',
    payload: res
  })
}

function* actionWatcher() {
  yield takeLatest('GET_INFO', fetchInfo)
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    actionWatcher(),
  ]);
}
```

Above, you can see that GET_INFO triggers fetch_info, but it updates the state after all other actions. I tried to fix it with useEffect but it did not help or I have not used it properly.

```
const DisputeCard = (props) => {

    const state = useSelector(state => state?.apiInfo?.apiInfo[0]?.results)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    useEffect(() => {

        dispatch(getInfo()) ; 
        console.log("State is ", state) // state returns undefined in the console

    }, [] );
```

[image: The console that contains the defined error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can not access the data before its get fetched. Either you can wait for the data to get fetched or pass a callback function to your action.

Use an0ther useEffect to wait for the data to get fetched, also you might have to wait for the data to render inside your component.

```
const state = useSelector(state => state?.apiInfo?.apiInfo[0]?.results)
const dispatch = useDispatch()

useEffect(() => {

    dispatch(getInfo()) ; 

}, [] );

useEffect(() => {
    if(state) {
      console.log("State is ", state);
    }

}, [state] );

if(!state) {
 return null;
}

return (
  <div>{state}</div>
)
```

Or pass a callback to your action:

```
export const getInfo = createAction("GET_INFO", (callback) => {
 return callback;
})

function* fetchInfo(action) {
 const callback = action.payload;
 const res = yield axios.get(URL).then((response) => response);
 callback(res)
 yield put({
  type: 'FETCH_INFO',
  payload: res
 })
 
 useEffect(() => {

  dispatch(
    getInfo((res) => {
     console.log("State is ", state) 
    })) ; 
   }, [] );
 }
```

Comment: I applied the first one and managed to see the state on the console but still, I cannot use it in the component by mapping over it.

Comment: You have to wait for tha data to get loaded before rendering it in your component. I have updated my answer, please have a look at it.

Comment: Great. I saw the data rendered properly in the component after hours of researching and it feels great.